# Use Butterworth and Chebychev filters

Tags: algorithms, transfer-function, signal-analysis

I need to calculate frequency response, phase response and apply to signals the Butterworth, Chebychev1 and Chebychev2 band-pass filters.

I'm developing in C++ with Qt, and I'm looking for algorithms or a (free) library to do that. I have my plotting solution, I just need the formulas.

The input values I have are the time/amplitude signal, the order of the filter and the low and high cut-off frequencies.

Comment: Do you know what frequency response and phase response *are*, conceptually? Are you looking for help on the concepts or the implementation?

Answer (score 6):

You might try Vincent Falco's [**Collection of Useful C++ Classes for Digital Signal Processing**](https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters).

The StackOverflow Question [**A C++ library for IIR filter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664686/a-c-library-for-iir-filter) offers a few more suggestions.

Finally: the hard part for Butterworth/Chebychev filters is really the design, not the implementation.  You might consider doing the design in Matlab (or Gnu Octave), or an online site like: **http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/**.  Writing the C code should be trivial once you know the coefficients for the recurrence relation.